# What makes spiral instability less harmful than Dutch roll?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, stability, dutch-roll

The FAA *[Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/)* says on [page 5-20](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/media/07_phak_ch5.pdf):

> Because it is more desirable for the aircraft to have “spiral
>   instability” than Dutch roll tendencies, most aircraft are designed
>   with that characteristic.

What are the grounds for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because spiral instability is easier to address by the pilot than Dutch Roll tendencies.

Spiral instability is instability about the longitudinal axis. For example, spiral instability means that if the right wing tip moves down, it continues to move down rolling the plane to the right. Its simple to detect and address with left aileron.

Additional information on spiral instability available here: http://www.faatest.com/books/FLT/Chapter17/SpiralInstability.htm

Dutch Roll causes cross-control-type movements across two axes, the vertical and longitudinal axis, such that when the airplane rolls right, it yaws to the left, then it swings back the other way and rolls left, while yawing to the right. This movement is difficult for the pilot to counteract and the inputs from the pilot can actually amplify these movements.

Additional information on Dutch Roll tendancies available here: http://www.faatest.com/books/FLT/Chapter17/FreeDirectionalOscillations.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there any recommended recovery procedures to break Dutch Roll, like "power idle, full opposite ruder, briskly yoke forward" for a spin recovery?

Comment: @lemonincider I've never flown a plane with Dutch Roll tendencies. I usually fly smaller airplanes. I believe that it is more of a problem for higher performance jets with sweptback wings. I believe reducing speed is how you address it. Pilot inputs often makes Dutch Roll worse. http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/aerodynamics/dutch-roll/

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative replies and the link!

Comment: *"Spiral instability is instability about the longitudinal axis"* ... is it? The spiral mode is a lateral-directional eigenmode, decoupled from the longitudinal modes (short and long period). As you correctly state it causes increasing roll, so I find the longitudinal part misleading at best.

Comment: @AEhere, I think he is referring to motion in longitudinal AXIS, rather than longitudinal modes, in that case it’s roll. And that’s true it’s a lateral-directional mode of motion.

Comment: @Kolom true, but also about the vertical axis, since roll and yaw are coupled. It is not outright wrong, just misleading due to the choice of words.

Comment: @Devil07 "simple to correct with aileron", not if you are near stall.  Perhaps better with aileron and rudder.  This would be more coordinated and generally safer.

Answer (score 6):

@Devil07 concentrated the answer on complexity of the movement (1D vs. 2D).

I'll talk about the response times, which will be different between isntabilities. Typically, the response time of the spiral mode will be longer than that of the dutch roll.

This makes it easier to control spiral for the pilot, which has more time to:

- Identify the situation
- Prepare the appropriate command mentally
- Synchronize its commands to the phase of the instability
- Apply the right amount of control force

In the case of faster instabilities, the pilot could have a hard time synchronizing its input to the right phase, and may in if failing to do so actually degrade the situation by adding pilot-induced perturbation.

Finally even when the airplane stays controlable and recovers, faster instabilities are more uncomfortable, as our incomfort "ceiling" seem to decrease with the square of the frequency of the oscillations. Since the spiral doesn't even always produce oscillation, the problem of comfort is never even brought up.

Comment: Well, spiral instability does not have any phase as it is simply diverging, not oscillating. So there is no need to synchronize the commands.